# passing /retrieving data from jquery to php function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have actually read all related answers to my question but I need a clear and simple example on how to properly implement my code below.

myHome.php

jquery

```
var url = "computeArea.php";
var data = $('thisForm').serialize();
$.post(url,data,function(response)); // how do i get the area being returned from  
                                       computeArea function? i need to save the 
                                       return value to a javascript variable
```

computeArea.php

```
function computeArea ($data){ // do i need to parse $data to make it an array?
    return $area;
}
```

im new to jquery and your help is very helpful. thank you!

Comment: Did you mean `$.post`? Also check question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Are you returning that or echoing? Your computeArea function in computeArea.php

Comment: ah yeah..sorry. it should be $.post.

Comment: i would like to return it and when it get back to myHome.php, i will use the returned value in my other functions.

Comment: You are doing a POST request to computeArea.php. It must echo/print its response -- $area on this case.

Comment: oh..so i need an input to echo the return value?

Comment: I posted my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a simple teste.

jQuery:

```
$.post("url/to/file.php",{variable_name: "hello"/*(we'll give this value to variable_name*/)},
  function(response){
    if(response>0)
       alert('Something went wrong');
    else
       alert(response);
});
```

Now, on server side:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['variable_name']) && $_POST['variable_name']!=="")
  echo $_POST['variable_name'];
 else
  echo 1;
?>
```

Comment: im getting "Something went wrong" output..is there something that I might missed?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$.post(url,data,function(response){
   alert(response)
});
```

ps: you are missing the `.` between `$` and `post`.

In your php code you could do that:

```
 echo json_encode($area);
```

Comment: I added the `echo json_encode($val)`  on the php bit, because with just return you won't get anything client side

Comment: ok, i tried this one but my page will only reload. something is wrong with the $.post() because alert ("hello") wont popup. any idea?

Comment: This might be because you do the serialize on form submit event, which if not prevented issues the page reload.

Comment: ok, the popup will now show but the response is empty. i even pass a literal string just to check if it will return the value but it did not. what could be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the use of post requests. This will not call the computeArea function in computeArea.php and pass data as its parameter:

```
var data = $('thisForm').serialize();
$.post(url,data,function(response));
```

You can do this instead for computeArea.php:

```
$data = $_POST['watever_you_are_serializing'];
// Do computations, etc.
$area = 123; // Contains computed area
echo $area;  // Or json_encode($area);
```

If you need to call that function from computeArea.php, then you can create a new file for $.post request (eg. computeArea2.php) and include computeArea.php from there. It would be something like this:

```
include 'computeArea.php';
$data = $_POST['watever_you_are_serializing'];
echo computeArea($data);
```

Comment: hello, i just made it this way to make it simpler..but i really need to post the value because the php function is a third party app.

Comment: If that's the case, then you can just call that function with the data you will get from $_POST as its parameter. And finally echo its return.

Answer (score -1):

Something along the lines of:

```
var url  = "computeArea.php",
    data = $('thisForm').serialize(),
    new_variable;

$.post(url, data, function(response) {

    new_variable = response;

});
```

Though I presume there's a bit more to your PHP script, as otherwise $area isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: by the way, regarding the $data , when my php function receives it, how can i convert it to an array?